# Is it possible to avoid the "use"/"retake" screen after taking a photo in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

i have hired a programmer to create an iPhone app for me. The purpose of the app is to take a photo and upload it to a server. We want to make a special purpose screen to review the photo before uploading it. This specially developed screen will crucially have zooming functionality.

He claims that after taking a photo, it is impossible to avoid the "use"/"reuse" screen to show up, so now we have two screens to review the photo. First the standard one from Apple, then our own with zoom. Is he right about that? It just sounds so unreasonable that Apple would put such a restriction.

Edit: I mean taking a photo using the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As par Apple's documentation

> To perform fully-customized image or movie capture, instead use the [AV
>   Foundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW10) as described in “Media Capture and Access to
>   Camera” in AV Foundation Programming Guide. To create a
>   fully-customized image picker for browsing the photo library, use
>   classes from the Assets Library framework. For example, you could
>   create a custom image picker that displays larger thumbnail images,
>   that makes use of EXIF metadata including timestamp and location
>   information, or that integrates with other frameworks such as Map Kit.
>   For more information, see Assets Library Framework Reference. Media
>   browsing using the [Assets Library framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) is available starting in
>   iOS 4.0

In short yes it is possible check out this [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. i have edited my question to clarify. I mean taking a photo using the camera. Does your answer still apply. The text from Apple seems to mention, picking an image from the gallery, which is a different use case and my question could be misunderstood.

Comment: yes it is applicable to taking photos using camera. If you ever checked instagram iPhone app (http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8) you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

[Update]

Use the `allowsEditing` property on your `UIImagePickerController`

`imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;`

Previous answer was a bit of a hack to take advantage of a code path that didn't show the buttons but wasn't awesome.

[Previous answer]

You can actually avoid it without going through the hassle of setting up your own image capture from AV Foundation.

Including the following will remove the need to show the "review" screen.  All you have to do is put in a few of your own buttons and wire them up to the appropriate functionality.

```
[self.imagePickerController setShowsCameraControls:NO];
```

Comment: how do you wire them up?

Answer (score -1):

It is a little bit too late I know, but for future reference:

This is far more simple that the answers already provided,
what you are looking for is the allowsEditing option.

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
```

That should be enough to avoid showing the "Retake"/"Use" screen after the user takes a picture.

Comment: Not enough to hide it.